# Getting error Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

I have used react-native when it was 0.50 now I'm using it again and it's 0.61.1
I am making an app and using `"react-navigation"` library for routing.

Since I'm using the `react-native-gesture-handler` according to the documentation I'm getting the error sometimes of `"Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name"` and when I close the app and reopen it, it's gone.

And especially `"Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name gestureHandlerRootView"` error comes so many times in-app.

here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Svf.png) of error in my console:
[image]

And because of this error, My app in release mode is also crashing as soon as I open it. I'm using React Native CLI not EXPO. I've searched in stack overflow and on other places but all the answers I got are saying remove `react-native-gesture-handler` from the expo.

But I'm not using EXPO what should I do? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I ran

```
npm ls react-native-webview
```

and was showed:

```
├─┬ react-native-webview-leaflet@5.0.2
│ └── react-native-webview@8.2.1
└── react-native-webview@11.0.2
```

Two webview.

I solve with:

```
yarn add react-native-webview-leaflet
```

That is, I had to reinstall 'react-native-webview-leaflet' probability because an update of 'react-native-webview'.

Comment: Install the lower version among

react-native-webview@8.2.1 , react-native-webview@11.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `find . -name react-native-{name-of-the-package}` and look for duplicates. They are probably detected and loaded each time (by `use_native_modules`), which leads to this error.
Try adjusting your dependencies (and look for deps of deps) to avoid such duplicated. At the end your adjustment should be visible in your lock file.